# Use RecordSelectionFormula in Crystal Reports with an IN Clause

Tags: c#, crystal-reports-xi

When I pass the following to a Crystal Report using the RecordSelectionFormula property, it fails to generate with the error "The ) is missing."  This is a valid Where Clause, just not sure how to use it in Crystal Reports XI.

```
SelectionFormula = "({vInventory_Items.DonorId} IN (8, 1))";
Report.ReportSelectionFormula = SelectionFormula;
```

And the error is;

```
Error in formula  Record_Selection: 
'({vInventory_Items.DonorId} IN (8, 1))'
The ) is missing.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following and it resolved my problem;

```
DataTable dtRawData = new DataTable();
SqlConnection loConn = ConnectionUtilities.getServerConnection();
loConn.Open();
SqlDataAdapter sdaSysObjects = new SqlDataAdapter(psSqlStatement, loConn);
sdaSysObjects.Fill(dtRawData);
Report.SetDataSource(dtRawData);
```